# array object deduplication. keep behind

Tags: javascript

```
let config = [{
    name: 1,
    state: 1,
    output: 'Y',
}, {
    name: 2,
    state: 1,
    output: 'A',
}, {
    name: 1,
    state: 100,
    output: 'Y',
}, {
    name: 2,
    state: 100,
    output: 'A',
}];


function unique(arr) {
    const res = new Map();
    return arr.filter((a) => !res.has(a.name) && res.set(a.name, 1))
}

console.log(unique(config))
```

It is reserved first, deleted behind,

But I need the behind, not the first.

how do I let it to keep behind and delete the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `Object.values` with `Array#reduce`

```js
let config = [{
    name: 1,
    state: 1,
    output: 'Y',
}, {
    name: 2,
    state: 1,
    output: 'A',
}, {
    name: 1,
    state: 100,
    output: 'Y',
}, {
    name: 2,
    state: 100,
    output: 'A',
}];
let result = Object.values(config.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item.name] = item, acc), {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks.but it will automatically help me sort by the number of the name, can let it don't do sort?